# AppModule is reinitialized for each route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 9 app, I have noticed that my service gets reinitialized/reinstantiated everytime I navigate from a route to another. After a long debug and trials, I decided to log in the constructor of AppModule and noticed that it gets recalled for every route.
NB: I inject my service using providedIn: 'root'. I have as well tried to declare the service in AppModule providers attribute instead of using providedIn, but still same result.

Any ideas?

Here is my AppModule:

```html
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({user : userReducer}),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    FontAwesomeModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){
    console.log('MODULE INIT');
  }
}
```

Here is my routing module:

```html
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you described makes me think your app is reloading a fresh state of itself each time you navigate. This can happen when:

- Asking your browser to reach an URL from scratch (like in another tab or pressing CTRL+R).
- Asking the native DOM of your app to route the user in a new context (like when using the native `href` attribute).

In any case your code seems right and you seem to have taken in consideration the consequences of using a singleton service so it is likely for the issue to not come from a service providing trouble.